# Workbooks.Open doesn't work for the second workbook

Tags: vba, excel, hssfworkbook

I am trying to prompt user to open the second excel workbook to do the "vlookup" inside the first workbook. But the macro get stuck after this code:

```
s2FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam, All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select second file")
If s2FileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set f2 = Workbooks.Open(s2FileName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
```

No error message pop out, it was just stuck in there even I press "ctrl + Break" to stop it.

But,when I try to segregate this code into two (before prompt to open the second workbook), it works fine. What's wrong with this code?

Here is the complete code:

```
Sub Mismatch()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim last As Integer


''OPEN FILE
sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam, All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select Authorization Issued Report File")
If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set auth = Workbooks.Open(sFileName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)

'unfilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BH$19322").AutoFilter Field:=15

Columns("AZ:AZ").EntireColumn.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"


'add new sheet
Set sht = Sheets.Add
sht.Name = "Mismatch"

Sheets("Mismatch").Select
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mismatch").Tab
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With




''find Mismatch
Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
Range("A1:BI1").Copy
Sheets("Mismatch").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

j = 2
For i = 2 To last
    Sheets("Authorizations Issued").Select
    If Range("$K$" & i).Value <> Range("$AZ$" & i).Value Then
        Range("$A$" & i & ":$BH$" & i).Copy
        Sheets("Mismatch").Select


        Range("$A$" & j).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        j = j + 1

    Else: j = j

    End If
Next i

Sheets("Mismatch").Select
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit





''vlookup SAP cust name
Columns("BA:BA").EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("BA2").Value = "SAP Cust Name"
mismatchLast = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("BA3").Select


s2FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam, All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select second file")
If s2FileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set f2 = Workbooks.Open(s2FileName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)


cmfLast = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

auth.Activate

For i = 3 To mismatchLast
    Selection.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AZ" & i & ",'[f2.name]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$" & cmfLast & ",2,0)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Set auth = Workbooks.Open(sFileName, UpdateLinks:=False)` or `Set auth = Workbooks.Open(sFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)`

Comment: You don't get an error because you set `DisplayAlerts` to false. An the error is in the `Workbooks.Open()` where you specify `UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever`. But that option does not exist: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx `UpdateLinks` can be either 0 or 3 but `xlUpdateLinksNever` has the value 2.